# Java. Блокировка readers - writers

Tags: java, многопоточность, асинхронность, синхронизация

Я знаю,  что в Java есть замок Readwritelock, позволяющий одновременно производить чтение нескольким потокам и блокирование записи,  или запись одним потоком и блокирование чтения. Есть ли какой то аналог,  с помощью которого можно также исключать возможность одновременного чтения и записи,  но с помощью которого много потоков могут  одновременно читать,  либо много потоков (не один,  как в Readwritelock) могут записывать?

Comment: смысл блокировок - предотвратить конкурентную запись...

Comment: Если несколько потоков будут одновременно производить запись без синхронизации, тогда ваши данные могут оказаться в неконсистентном состоянии. Смысл всех блокировок, как сказано выше - предотвратить такую ситуацию.

Comment: Чтение без синхронизации тоже чревато.  Можно не увидеть последних изменений.  По возможности надо использовать немутабельные объекты - тогда меньше потребуется синхронизаций